# DataTemplate trigger does not work

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatemplate

I have this simple piece of code that just doesn't work. The idea is that the icon in the tab header will change based on the content of the view model.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ProtocolViewModels:ProtocolTabItemContentViewModel}">
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Controls:TabItemHeader x:Name="tabItemHeader" 
                Header="{Binding TabHeader}" 
                Icon="{DynamicResource ProtocolCustom_TabIcon}"
                CloseCommand="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <LegacyProtocolViews:ProtocolTabItemContentView/>
    </TabItem>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProtocolViewModel.IsDakoOrigin}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="tabItemHeader" Property="Icon" Value="{DynamicResource ProtocolDako_TabIcon}"/>
        </DataTrigger>  
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

The property on the view model is notifying the view on change. Shouldn't this work?

**Edit**

TabItemHeader.xaml.cs

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(TabItemHeader), new PropertyMetadata(default(BitmapImage)));

    public BitmapImage Icon
    {
        get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }
```

TabItemHeader.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Workstation.Resources.Controls.TabItemHeader"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="persistingTabItem">
    <!-- skipped code -->
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=persistingTabItem, Path=Icon}"/> 
    <!-- skipped code -->
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you show your code and xaml for Controls:TabItemHeader and icon resources. I tried similar datatrigger and everything works fine. You can also try to change just headet of TabItemHeader by datatrigger to see if you have problems with datatrigger or icon

Comment: Added code sample. In the meanwhile I fixed this by using a ValueConverter. I would prefer the data trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. `Binding="{Binding ProtocolViewModel.IsDakoOrigin}"` -> `Binding="{Binding IsDakoOrigin}"` because it looks like IsDakoOrigin is a property of the DataContext of your template. You can also check output window then debug your application for binding errors

Comment: There are no binding exceptions. On my data context there is a property called ProtocolViewModel which has the IsDakoOrigin property.